# Finding the array index of an object with Javascript/React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that looks like so:

```
var skillsets = [
  {id: 'one', name: 'george'},
  {id: 'two', name: 'greg'},
  {id: 'three', name: 'jason'},
  {id: 'four', name: 'jane'},
];
```

what I would like to do is find the row based on a value given in the form of an id with Javascript.  For instance, if I put "id='two'" into the function, I'd like "1" to be returned as the row.

I know for a single row array, skillsets.indexOf['value'] would work, but that won't work for this JSON set.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

```
Skills = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
      return { id: 'default' };
    },

    getIndex(value, arr, prop) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i][prop] === value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; //to handle the case where the value doesn't exist
    },

    render: function() {

        var index = getIndex(id, skillsets, 'id');

        return (

            <section id="three" className="main style1 special">
                <div className="container">

                    <SkillsHeader skillsets={skillsets[index]}/>
                    {index}
                    <SkillsDetails details={details}/>
                    {index}

                </div>
            </section>

        );

    }
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple `for` loop wrapped in a reusable function is good enough:

```
function getIndex(value, arr, prop) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i][prop] === value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; //to handle the case where the value doesn't exist
}
```

Here, `value` is the value you want to match against, `arr` is the array of objects, and `prop` is the property of each iterable of the array which  should match the `value`.

You can use this function for any json with the structure you mentioned. In your specific case, call it like this:

```
var index = getIndex('one', skillsets, 'id');
```

Comment: Or perhaps return -1 if not found, to match what indexOf() does?

Comment: Yes, that would be better!

Comment: saying getIndex is undefined

Comment: most probably you are using it before declaring it. Show us your code.

Comment: I just included it in my original Q

Comment: see the answer's latest edit.

Comment: same error unfortunately..

Comment: Actually, I haven't worked with React so I dont know where you should place the function. Try putting the function in the render part of your code. Again, I am not sure where it should go but I think it will work if you the getIndex function in your render function.

Answer (score 5):

Lodash has a [findIndex](https://lodash.com/docs#findIndex) method that does exactly this.

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'active': false },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'active': true }
];

_.findIndex(users, function(o) { return o.user == 'barney'; });
// → 0

// The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
_.findIndex(users, { 'user': 'fred', 'active': false });
// → 1

// The `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.
_.findIndex(users, ['active', false]);
// → 0

// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.findIndex(users, 'active');
// → 2
```

But I think ES6 just supports the lambda version anyway (?) it's in the doc on [the flux page](https://fluxthis.io/#/docs/quick-start):

```
 removeTodo (id) {
        let index = this.todos.findIndex(todo => todo.get('id') === id);

        // remove the todo with the ID of id, but only if we have it to begin with
        this.todos = index > -1 ?
            this.todos.remove(index) :
            this.todos;
    },
```